# Userland implementation of PHP array key casting

Tags: php, arrays, casting

How can I implement PHP array key casting logic in PHP? One naive implementation could be the following.

```
function castKey($key) {
    $array = [$key => null];
    return key($array);
}
```

However, it seems wasteful to allocate a redundant array. I'd prefer to accurately emulate the casting logic. Of course it would be useful to see and understand the source code but I am not sure where to find this.

Empirically I have observed any scalar value can be stored as a key using the following casting rules.

- Integers are stored verbatim.
- Strings are stored as strings unless they *look like an integer*. I do not know exactly how PHP determines that a string looks like an integer; whether it is just `^\d+$` or something more complex.
- Booleans are cast to integer.
- Floats are cast to integer.

Comment: Don't floats as array keys become strings?

Comment: See the rules for array keys under the example: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-99 Also the source code is open source and is on github: https://github.com/php/php-src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-optimized version of the PHP array key casting logic can be found here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/dbf63cb98d642236da9b9b5c751f0d4f8223c77f/Zend/zend_API.c#L1630

The logic for detecting a numeric string (as far as array keys are concerned) can be found here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/16160386982a86e6ec7969c6c89707d38228f19e/Zend/zend_hash.c#L2442

So a userland implementation would look something like this:

```
function castKey($key) {
    if (is_int($key)) {
        return $key;
    }
    if (is_string($key)) {
        // Only keys of the form 0|-?[1-9][0-9]* in the
        // supported integer range are converted.
        $int = filter_var($key, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        if (false !== $int && '-0' !== $key) {
            return $int;
        }
        return $key;
    }
    if (null === $key) {
        return "";
    }
    if (is_bool($key) || is_double($key)) {
        return (int) $key;
    }
    if (is_resource($key)) {
        $id = (int) $key;
        trigger_error("Resource ID#$id used as offset, casting to integer ($id)");
        return $id;
    }
    throw new Exception('Illegal offset type');
}
```

Comment: Thanks NikiC! I would not have known to use `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`. Without your help I would have resorted to regex, which would presumably be a weak solution in case PHP's notion of which strings are integers changes between versions. I would also have never known resources were cast to integers.

Comment: As an aside, it is still unclear from that portion of the source how strings are cast to integer. Also, what is the need for the `$int >= 0` check?

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions You're right, I didn't double-check the implementation and thought that negative numbers wouldn't be converted ^^ I also linked the source of the numeric string check.

Comment: It is quite bizarre that an exception is made for `'-0'` but I'm glad we now understand this to be the case. I wish my C was strong enough to comprehend more of the source. It seems fairly straight forward, until I reach `*idx = (*tmp - '0');`; I do not understand any part of that!

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions `-0` is excluded because the mapping is supposed to be bijective. This would make `"0"` and `"-0"` map to the same key. `(*tmp - '0')` converts the ASCII character `*tmp` into a number, assuming it is between `'0'` and `'9'`. The reason is that the numbers occur continuously in ASCII, so `'0' - '0' == 0`, `'1' - '0' == 1` etc.

Comment: I don't see why that would be a problem since `-0 === 0`.